# Make a reusable component in Reach which takes same inputs but with different styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

How do you make a component in react which takes different classNames?

For eg let's have a reusable component that takes an image and a text. I want to use this component on 2 different pages but I want different font sizes for the text(18px & 24px).

I create the component and pass it the text and image. But how do I change the style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Reusable = ({styles, text , imgUrl}) => {
    return (
        <img src={imgUrl} alt={text} style={{...styles}} />
    )
}
```